# How to stop "Make your phone more social" prompts?

Tags: malware, popup

Alcatel One Touch 983, firmware version 2.3.7.

I am frequently interrupted with a black screen displaying this prompt:

> Make your phone more social
>
> Authorize the synchronizing which will make it easier for you to connect more with friends, share photos and links, and receive event reminders and notifications.
>
> <kbd>Allow</kbd> <kbd>Skip</kbd>

At first I thought it was Facebook, but then found that it was continuing after I killed the Facebook app. Moreover, it seems to stop when I switch my phone off and on again, but I don't know what's triggering it to start doing it again. Once started, it will sometimes pop up at minutely intervals, whether I tap Allow or Skip.

I'm not sure what it's actually doing. In any case, what can I do to stop this frequent interruption? A way to stop it for good would be preferable, but failing that, I would welcome advice on how to stop it for the time being without having to shut my phone down and possibly lose something I'm in the middle of doing.

Comment: You may want to get an app that lets you see the list of running processes and services. Then find it and delete it. Also, have you tried clicking the allow button and seeing which app it takes you to?

Comment: Could it be Facebook Home? If I recall, that's a separate process from the Facebook app.

Comment: @AlEverett you are correct this error is of facebook home.

Stewart use apps that can quarantine the apps 
for example 
1. **App Quarantine**
2. **Greenify**

may this help

Comment: @Jeffrey What would an app do over and above the built-in "Manage apps" facility?

Comment: @Jeffrey Before, Allow didn't seem to be doing anything, but now whenever I try it, it opens up Facebook to an error page "The page you requested cannot be displayed at the moment. It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may be broken our expired, our you may not have permission to view this page."

Comment: @Al I don't see an app "Facebook Home", but I see a few services listed under the fb app: MediaUploadService, BackgroundDetectionService, MqttPushService.

Answer (score 0):

Since a few days I have Alcatel Pop C3 and also experienced this annoying notification keeping reappearing. I didn't want it to have access to my Facebook account details.
As a result of many attempts I've figured out that it comes from default launcher. After I've installed ADW Launcher – you probably can choose any other from Play Store – the notification never showed up again :)

I hope will turn out to be helpful for someone!